# Rename files in a specific directory with bash/regex

Tags: bash, macos

I'm trying to create some hotfolders using LaunchControl and in part of the script I would like files in a specific directory to be renamed if they match certain criteria. The problem I'm having is not in the renaming part, it is in getting the script to call the directory. All the scripts or articles I find online only help in renaming the files, not in correctly calling the directory path as part of the renaming script. Doesn't seem it would be that hard but I can't work it out.

Here's what I have tried so far, which does nothing. If I CD to the directory though and leave out the part where it is calling the directory it will rename the files.

```
find . -mindepth 3 -type f -iregex '.*/Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/ASPERA/ASPERA_STAGING/.*' -print0 |
xargs -0 rename -v 's/([0-9]*)_LK/$1_standard/' \;
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "calling the directory". An example of what you want to rename to what would help too.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean by "calling the directory" is that the script itself is running at the root level and so I have to give it the directory path so that it knows which folder it should be looking in to rename files. I need to replace the words "LK" with "standard" and "ALT" with "alternate", an example would be 123454_LK.tif would become 123454_standard.tif, or 123454_ALT1.tif would become 123454_alternate1.tif

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this at the beginning of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

target_directory=/Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/ASPERA/ASPERA_STAGING
cd "$target_directory" || {
    echo "Error cd'ing to $target_directory" >&2
    exit 1
}
```

...and then leave off the `-iregex` part of your `find` command. Some notes on this:

- `find .` searches *under the current directory*, and if you haven't set that in the script, you don't know what it'll be. If you run that from the root directory ("/"), it'll search every directory and file you have permissions to (throwing errors for the ones you don't), and then discard the ones that aren't in the target directory; it's much better to just search the target directory. You could also accomplish this with `find "$target_dirctory"`.
- In my snippet above, I assumed that the directory is known and fixed, so it can just be included literally in the script. If that's not the case, something more complicated will be needed to set it correctly.
- I added an error check to the `cd` command -- you should **always** do this when using `cd` in a script; otherwise if something goes wrong, the rest of the script will execute in the wrong directory, with potentially weird/destructive consequences. Actually, I prefer to avoid using `cd` at all in scripts, and just use explicit paths -- it's generally safer and simpler.

Comment: (Credit to @DavidC.Rankin for pointing out an error in my error redirect :-)

Comment: Thanks for this. I think it's very close to working. Problem is it is returning "error cd'ing to $target_directory". It fails to rename files but it does actually cd to the Aspera_Staging directory after the error. Also is it able to search sub-directories inside Aspera_Staging? Because there are usually files in sub-directories too, I assumed -mindepth would handle that but perhaps not.

Comment: @JamesTrory I'm not sure I understand -- it should only give that error if it fails to `cd`, and the `exit` should keep it from doing anything else. Also, `find` normally searches all subdirectories, sub-subdirectories, sub-sub-subdirectories, etc; `-mindepth 3` will prevent it from listing any files less than 3 levels down.

Comment: Yes that was actually the problem, I had added `-mindepth 3` when it should be `-mindepth 2`, or just not have `mindepth` at all because it's not really necessary. Your solution does work, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your version of `find` has the `-execdir` feature, then you could do something like this (I cannot test right now):

```
find . -mindepth 3 -type f -iregex '.*/Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/ASPERA/ASPERA_STAGING/.*' -execdir rename -v 's/([0-9]*)_LK/$1_standard/' {} \;
```

Notice the `{}` near the end, it signifies the matched path. The `-execdir` flag executed the command in the directory of the matched file.